# I am getting this rubygem error

Tags: rubygems

It was totally fine until I rebooted my ubuntu machine. What do I do to get past it now?

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- colorize (LoadError)
```

The original script I run has error coming from a line that has the following
`require colorize`

Comment: Please explain the problem fully. That's far too little information for anyone to know the problem. What are you doing that causes the error? What is the full error? If the error originates from a file, then what's in that file?

Comment: I am running a script that is written by someone else.  But I am editing the Q to add little more context. Added more info. It is the colorize module

Comment: You can probably fix the issue by running `bundle install` (if the project contains a `Gemfile`), or `gem install colorize` (if it does not). However, what I was really trying to determine here is why *"It was totally fine until I rebooted my ubuntu machine"* ... What has changed?? Do you have multiple ruby versions installed? Did you re-install/uninstall anything? Has the script been updated? ...

Comment: Maybe, *for example*, you've recently installed `rvm`, but the setup was not complete - and the reboot fixed that?